# Cant set 3 toggle button text content which use same style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton

i have three toggle buttons which use a singe style resource on wpf, now i cant set their content, content is declared more than once error, each toggle button has a different content.
Each toggle button uses an image as background also.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Chromeless" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">

                    <Border BorderThickness="0" Width="197" Height="60">

                        <ContentPresenter TextElement.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding TextElement.FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
    <Image  x:Key="page1Pressed" Source="/graph_engine;Component/cucaracha/LD3/button_1.png" Height="60" Width="197" />
    <Image  x:Key="page1" Source="/graph_engine;Component/cucaracha/LD3/button_1_pressed.png" Height="60" Width="197" />

    <Image  x:Key="page2Pressed" Source="/graph_engine;Component/cucaracha/LD3/button_2.png" Height="60" Width="197" />
    <Image  x:Key="page2" Source="/graph_engine;Component/cucaracha/LD3/button_2_pressed.png" Height="60" Width="197" />

    <Image  x:Key="page3Pressed" Source="/graph_engine;Component/cucaracha/LD3/button_3.png" Height="60" Width="197" />
    <Image  x:Key="page3" Source="/graph_engine;Component/cucaracha/LD3/button_3_pressed.png" Height="60" Width="197" />

</UserControl.Resources>
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
    <Grid Height="60" Name="grid1" Width="591" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="197" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="197" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="197" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton  Style="{StaticResource Chromeless}"  Name="page1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Checked="page1_Checked" Unchecked="page1_Unchecked">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="page1"/>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource Chromeless}"  Name="page2" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Unchecked="page2_Unchecked" Checked="page2_Checked">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="page2"/>
        </ToggleButton>

        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource Chromeless}"  Name="page3" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="{x:Null}" Checked="page3_Checked" Unchecked="page3_Unchecked">
            <DynamicResource ResourceKey="page3"/>
        </ToggleButton>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you can't change the image when you pressed down the toggle button? You only set a image to the content of toggle button. You can use Visual State Manager to change the background like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx)

If you just want to set the image and failed. Please check the image path.

Comment: i cant set the content (caption) for those toggles..it says content already declared